# java.lang.RunTimeException: Method called after release() when resuming camera activity

Tags: android, android-camera

Firstly I would like to say that I have researched this issue extensively and I realise that quite a few solutions have been posed on this site (and others) but absolutely none of them have worked for me.

Upon taking a picture my application allows the user to add Exif tags to the photo. After adding the data I would like the user to be able to return to the camera and continue taking pictures. However on returning to my camera activity I experience the aforementioned `java.lang.RunTimeException: Method called after release()` error when I try to take another picture.

Now I realise that this is caused by the fact that I am trying to use the camera after I have released it and according to the Android API I need to re-`open()` the camera in my `onResume()` method. When I do this however I get a `Failed to connect to camera service` error.
Many people have also suggested placing `mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null)` in the `onResume()` method but then this just also causes a `Method called after release()` error.

Here is my logCat:

```
01-04 10:03:08.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 10:03:08.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called      
                                            after release()
01-04 10:03:08.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
01-04 10:03:08.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:789)
01-04 10:03:08.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:753)
01-04 10:03:08.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): at com.example.unititest.CameraActivity$6.onClick(CameraActivity.java:180)
01-04 10:03:08.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-04 10:03:08.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
01-04 10:03:08.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-04 10:03:08.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-04 10:03:08.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-04 10:03:08.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-04 10:03:08.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 10:03:08.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-04 10:03:08.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
01-04 10:03:08.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-04 10:03:08.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Where error is thrown:

```
            // Add a listener to the Capture button
        Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    //Picture is taken and saved to file
                    //ERROR IS THROWN HERE  
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                }
            }           
        );
```

Comment: Where are you releasing the camera?  In `onPause()` or somewhere else?

Comment: I don't actually release it anywhere myself. Initially I was releasing it in my overridden `onPause()` and `onStop()` methods but that wouldn't even let me resume my camera activity so I just removed that.

Comment: The fact that you don't release it yourself might actually be the problem: under certain circumstances, this causes the camera to be left in an unstable state and trying to re-open it causes the `Failed to connect to camera service`. You should probably investigate why releasing it in your `onPause` or `onStop` caused issues and solve that first.

Comment: I have literally spent hours trying different combinations of methods in `onPause()` and `onStop()` as well as researching the problem with absolutely no success.